# Creating a fading shadow in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, graphic-styles

How do you create shadows for every piece like in this image:

[image]

Comment: Create the shadows one by one. What have you _tried_? Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 4):

1. Duplicate
2. Gradient
3. Angle 85.7°
4. Change Slider Opacity
5. Change Slider Location
6. Change Opacity

[image]

Final Image:

[image]

Comment: nice, very simple. What did you use to record the screen with that zoom over the cursor?

Comment: Oh, I appreciate your corrections so much, thank you! Camtasia; It is the highlight cursor feature.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one method

1. Create pieces with simple linear gradients
2. Draw a curved shape with the *Pen Tool*, fill it black and add a *Gaussian* blur effect.
3. In the *Appearance* panel, set the *Opacity* to about 50%, and the blending mode to *Darken*. Finally use a copy of the purple piece, pasted in place, and set it as a clipping path to contain the shadow.

[image]

Repeat for other pieces of the design.